# How to calculate Sortino ratio from a weighted portfolio with Python?

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization

In this working example I'm able to calculate a Sharpe ratio (with rf=0) from a weighted portfolio of 3 securities, but how can I modify the code bellow so it calculates a Sortino ratio ?

```
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data

tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', '^GSPC']
start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = '2016-12-31'

weights = [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]

# Fetch data
df = data.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)['Close']

# Calculate historical returns
returns = df.pct_change(1).dropna()

# Weighted mean returns
exp_rets = returns.mean()
mean = sum(exp_rets * weights)

# Standard deviation
var = np.dot(np.dot(weights, returns.cov()), weights)

# Sharp ratio
sr = mean / np.sqrt(var)

print(sr)
0.054270779230564975
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Sortino ratio in Python:

Doing my own due dilligence, I found a paper depicting the [formula for the Sortino ratio](https://www.cmegroup.com/education/files/rr-sortino-a-sharper-ratio.pdf), which follows the same setup as from [this link](https://www.futuresmag.com/2013/01/31/sortino-ratio-better-measure-risk) described in an earlier comment. For brewity, the formula for the Sortino ratio can be specified as:

$$ S = \frac{R - T}{TDD} $$

where $R$ is the average period return and $T$ is the target return (also referred to as mean acceptable return, MAR). Moreover,

$$
TDD = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \min\left(0, X_i - T\right)^2}
$$

denotes the target downside deviation, with $X_i$ being the $i$'th return. Using the above formula we can calculate the Sortino ratio in Python. Disregarding the first part of your code above (*defining weights, getting stock data, etc*), we can calculate the Sortino ratio using the following function:

```
def SortinoRatio(df, T):
    """Calculates the Sortino ratio from univariate excess returns.


    Args:
        df ([float]): The dataframe or pandas series of univariate excess returns.
        T ([integer]): The targeted return. 
    """

    #downside deviation:

    temp = np.minimum(0, df - T)**2
    temp_expectation = np.mean(temp)
    downside_dev = np.sqrt(temp_expectation)

    #Sortino ratio:

    sortino_ratio = np.mean(df - T) / downside_dev

    return(sortino_ratio)
```

You can now construct portfolio returns, define your specified target return $T$ and feed these into the function:

```
#portfolio returns:
port_ret = returns.dot(weights)

#-------------------output:-----------------------
print(np.round(SortinoRatio(port_ret, T = 0),4))
0.0782
```

This results in a Sortino ratio of 0.0782.

## Verification:

**A good way to validate the above function, is to find an already implemented function from a "respectable" source**. Here, the `PerformanceAnalytics` package from `R` contains a function that calculates the Sortino ratio. Using this function on the first 10 rows of your dataframe (*called ret*) we get the following:

```
#R code:
ret <- matrix( 
c(0.001729,  0.000323,  0.003116,
-0.015906, -0.006137,  0.000546,
-0.001849, -0.010400,  0.004001,
 0.006648,  0.006897,  0.002882,
-0.008821, -0.012720,  0.001747,
-0.011375, -0.006607, -0.009381,
 0.014106,  0.009312,  0.008326,
-0.005792,  0.020099,  0.002426,
-0.016712, -0.003230, -0.010823,
0.044238, 0.007777, 0.012500), nrow = 10, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

weights <- c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)

portret <- as.xts(ret %*% weights, order.by = as.Date(1:10))

#-------------------output:-----------------------
round(SortinoRatio(portret, MAR = 0), 4)
                           [,1]
> Sortino Ratio (MAR = 0%) 0.1664
```

Here, the function in Python gives the same result (there's a slight difference for higher decimal-points):

```
return_test = returns.head(10)@weights

#-------------------output:-----------------------
print(np.round(SortinoRatio(return_test, T = 0),4))
0.1664
```

---

There is a slight deviation between the two results for more decimal-points (*>5*) which might be attributable to different precision-based values used between the languages. **Nevertheless, I hope this helps you with your implementation**.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation and code example, thanks!

Comment: I suppose target return is 0 by default

Comment: I chose $T = 0$ in the above example to mimic the Sortino ratio you tried to specify yesterday, in your now-deleted question. It is a user-defined parameter, and the easiest thing for me, was to set it equal to 0 :-)